# Removing last comma in array when looping without turning it into a string

Tags: php, loops, tags

I have a set of tags that I stored in the database separated by spaces as a string. When I echo them out with PHP, I explode them and loop through them with a for loop.

My code looks something like this:

```
$tags = explode(' ',$c['art_tags']); for($i=0;$i<count($tags);$i++){ echo "<a href='#'>".$tags[$i]."</a>".", ";}
```

So far I've only seen posts with answers to use implode, but if I use implode, I wouldn't be able to click on the individual tags because it would be a string..

So I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of the last comma when I'm looping the tags array for each tag. It would ultimately appear like this:

```
<a href="">tag1</a>,<a href="">tag2</a>,<a href="#">tag3</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just change the comma to the beginning of the echo in the for loop and implement a condition to check if its the first tag...  like this:

```
<?php
$c='bob sally butch jim';

$tags = explode(' ',$c); 

for($i=0;$i<count($tags);$i++)
    { 
        if($i === 0)
            {
                echo "<a href='#'>" . $tags[$i] . "</a>";
            }

        else
            {
                echo ", <a href='#'>" . $tags[$i] . "</a>";
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: @rmorr `count($tags)` is constant. I recommend to remove (replace by variable) it from `for`-loop condition section for better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) + [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
<?php
$tags = explode(' ', $c['art_tags']);
$tags = array_map(function($tag){ return '<a href="#">' . $tag . '</a>'; }, $tags);

echo implode(', ', $tags);
?>
```

Working example @ [***PhpFiddle***](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/18a-3r0)

Comment: Also thanks for the example in php fiddle. I didn't know there was a php fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trim()` or `rtrim();`

Comment: I thought trim was only valid for strings..?